# Python subprocess.communicate() does not capture output from simple binary

Tags: python, c, linux, bash, python-2.7

I'm trying to use Python to capture the output from this compiled C program:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<time.h>

int main() {
  srand(time(NULL));

  do {
    int r = rand();
    printf("%s\t%d\n", "my.key", r);
    usleep(100000);
  } while ( 1 );
}
```

If I run the following, I see the output from my binary interleaved with my python output as I would expect (and since stdout/stderr are not `subprocess.PIPE`, `self.output` and `self.error` are `None`).

```
self.process = Popen(shlex.split(self.path_to_binary), stdout=sys.stdout, stderr=sys.stderr);
self.output, self.error = self.process.communicate();
```

However, if I change the `stdout` and `stderr` arguments to `subprocess.PIPE`, `subprocess.communicate()` still doesn't capture anything in either `self.output` or `self.error`.

```
self.process = Popen(shlex.split(self.path_to_binary), stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE);
self.output, self.error = self.process.communicate();
```

The same snippet of code *will* capture the output of a bash script:

```
#!/bin/bash
while true ; do
    printf "%s\t%s\n" "my.key" "$RANDOM"
    usleep 100000
done
```

Neither script exits naturally - they are both killed via `self.process.kill()` after about three seconds.

Why can Python capture the bash output but not the binary output? Is there anything that I can do on the *Python* side of the equation to capture the output from the binary, *without modifying the C source*?

Comment: First of all, __flush__ outout in your C program with `fflush(stdout);`.

Answer (score 1):

The output is being buffered:

You need to flush from c:

```
int main() {
  srand(time(NULL));

  do {
    int r = rand();
    printf("%s\t%d\n", "my.key", r);
    usleep(100000);
    fflush(stdout);
  } while ( 1 );
}
```

And iterate over stdout.readline, `communicate` is waiting for the process to finish so you are not going to get any output:

```
for line in iter(p.stdout.readline,""):
    print(line)
```

If you want the output unbuffered without changing the c code you can use [stdbuf](http://manpages.courier-mta.org/htmlman1/stdbuf.1.html) on linux:

```
p = Popen(["stdbuf","-oL","binary"], stdout=PIPE, stderr=PIPE)

for line in iter(p.stdout.readline,""):
    print(line)
```

`-oL` will be line buffered.

Using   `for line in iter(p.stdout.readline,"")` will work without changing the c code but the output will be buffered.

Comment: So why can Python capture/recognize the buffered output if I specify `Popen(*args*, stdout=sys.stdout, stderr=sys.stderr`? Is there some way to copy the process buffer *only* into a new string without using `subprocess.PIPE`?

Comment: Are you saying  `stdout=sys.stdout` shows you output?

Comment: you can use `stdout=PIPE` and iterate over stdout.readline but the output will be buffered